# canvas's element rotation issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

Well, i'm actually not able to find a way to center the circle of the rotation with the canvas.

I would like to put the origin of the circle as the same of an element (`canna()`), I tried but it does not work well:

45 =  tank width; 
35 = tank height;
50 = gray bar width (canna());
10 = gray bar height (canna());

```js
let c;
let player1;

function startGame() {
  map.start();
  c = new Console();
  player1 = new Tank1();
}

let map = {
  canvas: document.getElementById("game"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 100;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.interval = setInterval(updateMap, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}


function floor() {
  this.ctx = map.context;
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "#3D9970";
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, (map.canvas.height - 50), map.canvas.width, 50); //floor
}

class Console {
  constructor() {
    this.alpha = document.getElementById("angle");
  }

  deg() {
    degRange.value = this.alpha.value;
  }
}

class Tank1 {
  constructor() {
    this.colors = ["purple", "red", "yellow", "green"];
    this.moves = 3;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((map.canvas.width / 2) - 50) + 50);
    this.y = 100;
  }

  canna() {
    let rad = parseInt(c.alpha.value) * Math.PI / 180;
    this.ctx = map.context;

    //THE PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    this.ctx.translate((this.x + 20 / 3.5) + 50 / 2, this.y + 10 / 2);
    this.ctx.rotate(-rad);
    this.ctx.translate(-((this.x + 20 / 3.5) + 50 / 2), -(this.y + 10 / 2));
    this.ctx.fillRect((this.x + 22.5), (this.y - 12), 50, 10);
    this.ctx.restore();
  }

  newPos() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
  }

  hitBottom() {
    let floorBottom = (map.canvas.height - 50) - 25;

    if (this.y > floorBottom) {
      this.y = floorBottom;
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.canna();
    this.ctx = map.context;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[0];
    this.ctx.fillRect((this.x + 8), (this.y - 15), 30, 16);
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 45, 25);
  }
}

function updateMap() {
  map.clear();
  floor();
  player1.newPos();
  player1.update();
}

//CONSOLE
startGame();
let degRange = document.querySelector('.displayAngle')
c.deg();

degRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!check.test(degRange.value)) {
    degRange.value = '';
  } else {
    c.alpha.value = degRange.value;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

input[type="range"]:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#game {
  display: block;
}

.console {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.form-a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-a>div {
  display: flex;
}

.form-a>div>p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.display {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline-width: 0;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
<div class="console">
  <div class="form-a">
    <label>Angolation</label>
    <div>
      <input id="angle" type="range" oninput="c.deg()" value="0" max="360" />
      <input class="display displayAngle" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i center the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are setting your x and y values on the cannon and also trying to translate the cannon the same amount. Translate literally moves an entire sheet of canvas with that object drawn on it to the position you want. If you also set an x and y on the object too it will move twice as much. When you translate you are pretty much saying put the (0,0) (top-left) of this sheet of canvas at x and y coordinates of the visible canvas. It's hard to explain since its all one canvas but think of it as each object drawn has it own sheet that can be moved and rotated.

Try this out and see if it is what you are trying to do

```
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    this.ctx.translate(this.x + 22.5, this.y - 5);
    this.ctx.rotate(-rad);
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, -5, 50, 10);  
    this.ctx.restore();
```

With `save()` and `restore()` you don't need to translate the object back after. I set the y value of the cannon to -5 in order to position the center of the end of the cannon on the (0,0) of its sheet of canvas. When rotating this will make sure it rotates from the center of that end.